# How to pass value with std::move in lambda function

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

First of all I apologize if it gets too long, as the problem can be detailed quickly, however, I describe a good part of the environment to perhaps come and help.

I'm developing a tool in C++ that analyzes genomic data (FASTQ data specifically). In case you don't know, a FASTQ file contains raw reads of genetic sequence, where each set of 4 lines of this file represents a read of the genome.
Well, as the processing of a read does not depend on other reads (in my case), I intend to parallelize the work with threads to save processing time.

When searching, I found some libraries ready and I'm trying to adapt. Right now I'm trying to use Thread Pool (specifically this lib -> https://github.com/log4cplus/ThreadPool/) but I'm having some problems with the integration.

I will detail the general algorithm a little.
Each iteration in the FASTQ file takes a set of 4 lines from the file and stores it in this struct.

```
struct READ  {
            std::string name; // Small size
            std::string comment; // Small size
            std::string seq; // String ranging between 0 and 1000 characters
            std::string which; // The same amount of 'seq' characters  
};
```

That is immediately passed as a value to the foreign function to perform the (non-trivial) task managed by the Thread Pool.

```
ThreadPool pool (4); // Creating thread pool with 4 threads

while (exist_read) // as long as there are reads to be processed -> read set of 4 lines
{
  Read read;
  read = next_read (); // read will contain 4 lines of the file read in the iteration
  pool.enqueue ([read] {
    Search (read); // search function performs non-trivial search work
  });
}
```

As can be seen, I passed the values ​​in the lambda function and tested it with several threads, but I ended up having inferior performance when using single-thread.
So I was suggested to use a movable object. And with great help, I got this struct.

```
struct READ
{
    READ () = default;
    READ (READ &&) = default;
    READ & operator = (READ &&) = default;
    std::string name;
    std::string comment;
    std::string seq;
    std::string which;
};
```

And the lambda function has changed to:

```
pool.enqueue ([r {std::move(read)}] {
   Search (std::move(r));
});
```

In addition, did update the reading of the FASTQ file of:

```
[...]
Read read;
read.name = lines[0];
read.seq = lines[1];
read.comment = lines[2];
read.qual = lines[3];
[...]
```

To:

```
[...]
Read read;
read.name = std::move(lines [0]);
read.seq = std::move(lines [1]);
read.comment = std::move(lines [2]);
read.qual = std::move(lines [3]);
[...]
```

However, I still haven't been able to test the performance, because I'm having the following [print_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rn0N.png)

> error: function "READ::READ (const READ &)" (declared implicitly)
> cannot be referenced - it is a deleted function C / C ++ (1776)

I searched other forums but I couldn't find an answer that would suit my problem.
If anyone can help me with this problem I will be very grateful. I hope I have been clear.
In addition, I also accept suggestions for other alternatives.

Thanks.

Comment: You will be surprised to learn that your original `READ` was ***already***  a movable object, and explicitly declaring move constructor and operator accomplished absolutely nothing whatsoever, except to delete the implicit copy constructor which then resulted in this compilation error. Most likely, the original code should've been, simply `pool.enqueue ([read=next_read()] {`, then cross your fingers and hope that RVO does the trick.

Comment: What's the `Search` definition?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: We don’t have to hope for RVO here—even in C++14, you would get an automatic move for that init-capture, which is plenty cheap.